# Android Recurring Task Run In Background

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, recurring

I am having some problem when trying to do a recurring task in Android. Here is how I populate my list view:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String recurID;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recur_listview_row, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txt_ddate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayRecurDate);
        viewHolder.txt_damount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayRecurAmount);
        viewHolder.txt_dfrequency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayFrequency);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    recurID = _recurlist.get(position).getRecurringID();
    // Format and calculate the next payment date based on frequency
    try {
        String dateStr = _recurlist.get(position).getRecurringStartDate();
        String frequencyStr = _recurlist.get(position).getFrequency();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateStr));

        if (frequencyStr.equals("Daily")) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            viewHolder.txt_ddate.setText("Next Payment On: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        } else if (frequencyStr.equals("Weekly")) {
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
            viewHolder.txt_ddate.setText("Next Payment On: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
        } 
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    viewHolder.txt_dfrequency.setText(_recurlist.get(position).getFrequency().trim());

    if (_recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType().equals("W")) {
        viewHolder.txt_damount.setTextColor(Color.rgb(180, 4, 4));
        viewHolder.txt_damount.setText("Credit $ " + amount);
    } else if (_recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType().equals("D")) {
        viewHolder.txt_damount.setTextColor(Color.rgb(8, 138, 8));
        viewHolder.txt_damount.setText("Debit $ " + amount);
    }

    // Get current date
    String currentDate = "Next Payment On: " + dateFormat.format(new Date());

    // If current date matches with the next payment date, insert new
    // transaction record
    if (currentDate.equals(viewHolder.txt_ddate.getText())) {
        DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(Recurring.this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        TransactionRecModel trm = new TransactionRecModel();
        CategoryController cc = new CategoryController(mDbHelper.open());

        trm.setDate(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        if (_recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType().equals("W")) {
            trm.setType("W");
        } else if (_recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType().equals("D")) {
            trm.setType("D");
        }
        trm.setAmount(Float.parseFloat(formatAmount));

        TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(mDbHelper.open());
        if (trc.addTransactionRec(trm)) {
            // After successfully insert transaction record, update the
            // recurring start date
            rm = new RecurringModel();
            rm.setRecurringID(recurID);
            rm.setRecurringStartDate(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

            RecurringController rc = new RecurringController(mDbHelper.open());
            if (rc.updateRecurringDate(rm)) {
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

From the code I tried to get the current date and compare with the next payment date computed based on frequency. However, with these code, it does not run in background.

Let's say I set a recurring event which will be repeating daily yesterday. But I did not run the application today. By right, the recurring should run in background and execute the recurring. But somehow, it does not.

I wonder do I need some service like AlarmManager to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So what I've changed is the part when I try to compare the dates, if the dates matched, it will call the alarmManager and parse some values along the way:

```
if (currentDate.equals(viewHolder.txt_ddate.getText())) {
    long when = new Date().getTime();
    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarm.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("RecurID", recurID);                
    notificationIntent.putExtra("Date", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    notificationIntent.putExtra("Description", viewHolder.txt_ddesc.getText().toString());
    notificationIntent.putExtra("Type", _recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType());
    notificationIntent.putExtra("Amount", Float.parseFloat(formatAmount));
    notificationIntent.putExtra("CategoryID", viewHolder.txt_dcat.getText().toString());
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationCount, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
}
```

And in my ReminderAlarm class, I am executing the insert and update SQL statement:

```
public class ReminderAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String recurID = intent.getStringExtra("RecurID");
    String date = intent.getStringExtra("Date");
    String description = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
    String type = intent.getStringExtra("Type");
    Float amount = Float.parseFloat(intent.getStringExtra("Amount"));
    String categoryID = intent.getStringExtra("CategoryID");

    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(ReminderAlarm.this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    TransactionRecModel trm = new TransactionRecModel();
    CategoryController cc = new CategoryController(mDbHelper.open());

    trm.setDate(date);
    trm.setTransDescription(description);
    if (type.equals("W")) {
        trm.setType("W");
    } else if (type.equals("D")) {
        trm.setType("D");
    }
    trm.setAmount(amount);

    // Get the categoryID based on categoryName
    String catID = cc.getCatIDByName(categoryID);
    trm.setCategory(catID);

    TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(mDbHelper.open());
    if (trc.addTransactionRec(trm)) {
        // After successfully insert transaction record, update the
        // recurring start date
        RecurringModel rm = new RecurringModel();
        rm.setRecurringID(recurID);
        rm.setRecurringStartDate(date);

        RecurringController rc = new RecurringController(mDbHelper.open());
        if (rc.updateRecurringDate(rm)) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You absolutely should not be doing all this work in your `Adapter`. You *should* do it in a `Loader`, then pass the display-ready data to the adapter. You should read the tutorials on d.android.com, because nearly-everything you're doing here is wrong.

Comment: Sorry but Loader means the onCreate method of activity or?

Comment: @PaulBurke Would you mind to elaborate a little bit? Cause I have no idea on how to do this at all

Answer (score 1):

Your `Adapter` should receive data that is **ready to be displayed**. `getView` is called every time a `ListView` item comes onto screen, so you want to keep your work here to under 16ms if you hope to maintain 60fps scrolling. Because of this, you should do all heavy work *before* it gets to the Adapter.

Since database data is often not display-ready, you would typically use a `Loader` to get the data, and turn it into a list of "items" that are Adapter-ready. This should happen in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, and you fill the `Adapter` in `onLoadFinished`. This often means creating a new POJO to represent the display data.

Best place to start is the [Loader tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

If you want to set a recurring task, you should use the `AlarmManager`, as you suspected. The `AlarmManager` would typically trigger a `BroadcastManager`, which in turn would spawn a `Service` to do the work.

Follow the [AlarmManager tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for more details.

Comment: But how should I trigger the alarm as the example you provided are triggered over certain period of time. But my situation is based on the next payment date and current date.

Comment: For your case, I suppose you'd determine those dates in the `Loader`, and set the alarms there. The `Adapter` should only be concerned with what is being displayed.

Comment: The Loader is it the part where I fetch all the data from database? Check my edited portion

Comment: Yes. Please read my answer carefully. All of your database operations should be in the `Loader`. Database creation should happen even before the `Loader`. Typically when you `open()` your DbHelper instance.

Comment: Okay but come to this part, how do I set the alarm manager to execute the insert and update SQL method when the current date and next payment date matches?

Comment: `AlarmManager` sends an `Intent` and you attach necessary data to the `Intent` extras. This starts a `Service` to process and update the data.

Comment: I modified my codes already. Could you please help me check the edited portion?

Comment: The better pattern would be to follow my advice above. `BroadcastManager`s are short-lived processes, and can be killed at any time. It's recommended to start a `Service` in your `BroadcastManager` to do the actual database work.

Comment: I've tested the codes again but it does not work. Any ideas because it's not running in the background